# Помогите разобраться в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка `^\\+?([0-9]+)(@.*)?$` и пример к ней "79101234567", который почему-то не подходит. Почему? И какой бы номер по ней мог подойти?

Comment: А какой язык, какой метод? [Смотрите, всё "прекрасно" работает](https://regex101.com/r/Rlxv5u/2).

Comment: Язык специфический, но регулярки там вроде perl'овые.

Comment: У вас же в самом начале выражения проверяется на то что бы строка начиналась обязательно на 1 и более обратных косых,

Comment: В вашем выражении ожидается символ @

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov не обязательно

Comment: @Mike: Если ТС опубликовал *литерал*, не текст, то всё может и работать. Нужен код.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov а, да

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov Не, @ и то что после нее может быть, но не обязательно (вопросительный знак после скобок задает необязательность)

Comment: Кстати часто помогает этот сайт https://regexper.com/

Comment: @TimurMusharapov: Всё равно, опубликуйте код, добавьте тег языка, опишите, какой текст должна находить регулярка.

Comment: Там в общем все сложнее было, и изначально номер пропускался через пару методов, которые его преобразовывали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`79101234567` не подойдёт, потому что в начале ожидается косая черта (фрагмент `^\\`).
Примеры, которые подойдут

```
\79101234567

\\\\79101234567

\79101234567@test
```

Общий совет: смотрите свои регулярки на сайте https://regex101.com/. Там они наглядно раскладываются на составные части.